# Does spring cloud dataflow for batch use only require skipper?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to get a handle on the architecture of spring cloud dataflow. Specifically in using it to orchestrate purely batch pipelines. I've deployed all the components in k8s and noticed I can deploy the skipper component without a middleware (Kafka / RabbitMQ) and run batch jobs successfully through the server component.

Per the docs I can see skipper is used to orchestrate streaming jobs. Is skipper (and subsequently the Kafka/RabbitMQ middleware) a necessary piece of spring cloud dataflow when using for purely batch jobs or tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Spring Cloud Skipper is **not** needed when you **only** run the task (batch) applications.

The idea of Spring Cloud Skipper was to provide continuous deployment experience for **Streaming** applications. The continuous deployment support for task(batch) applications was embedded into Spring Cloud Data Flow itself since SCDF 2.3.x.

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check!